# pipe and redirection speed, `pv` and UUOC

Tags: pipe, cat, pv

I was testing different methods to produce random garbage and comparing their speed by piping  output to `pv`, as in:

```
$ cmd | pv -s "$size" -S > /dev/null
```

I also wanted a "baseline reference", so I measured the the fastest "generator", `cat`, with the fastest source, `/dev/zero`:

```
$ cat /dev/zero | pv -s 100G -S > /dev/null
 100GiB 0:00:33 [2,98GiB/s] [=============================>] 100%
```

**3GB/s**, that's pretty impressive, specially compared to **~70MB** I get from `/dev/urandom`.

But hey, for the special case of `/dev/zero` I don't need `cat`! Just for the kicks I removed this textbook [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html):

```
$ < /dev/zero pv -s 100G -S > /dev/null
 100GiB 0:00:10 [9,98GiB/s] [=============================>] 100%
```

What??? Almost **10GB/s**? How can removing `cat` and a pipe more than *triple* the speed? If using a slower source such as `/dev/urandom` the difference is negligible. Is `pv` doing some voodoo magic? So I tested:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero iflag=count_bytes count=200G of=/dev/null status=progress
205392969728 bytes (205 GB, 191 GiB) copied, 16 s, 12,8 GB/s
```

**12,8 GB/s**! Same ballpark as `pv`, and 4 times faster than using pipes.

Is `cat` to blame? Are pipes so much different than redirection? Afterall, both go to `pv` as `stdin`, right? What can explain this huge difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The killer is the use of two processes.

With `cat | pv`, `cat` reads and writes, and `pv` reads and writes, and both processes need to run:

```
$ perf stat sh -c 'cat /dev/zero | pv -s 100G -S > /dev/null'
 100GiB 0:00:26 [3.72GiB/s] [====================================================================================>] 100%            

 Performance counter stats for 'sh -c cat /dev/zero | pv -s 100G -S > /dev/null':

         34,048.63 msec task-clock                #    1.267 CPUs utilized          
         1,676,706      context-switches          #    0.049 M/sec                  
             3,678      cpu-migrations            #    0.108 K/sec                  
               304      page-faults               #    0.009 K/sec                  
   119,270,941,758      cycles                    #    3.503 GHz                      (74.89%)
   137,822,862,590      instructions              #    1.16  insn per cycle           (74.94%)
    32,379,369,104      branches                  #  950.974 M/sec                    (75.14%)
       216,658,446      branch-misses             #    0.67% of all branches          (75.04%)

      26.865741948 seconds time elapsed

       1.257950000 seconds user
      38.893870000 seconds sys
```

With `pv` only, there’s just `pv` reading and writing, no context switching needed  (or hardly any):

```
$ perf stat sh -c '< /dev/zero pv -s 100G -S > /dev/null'
 100GiB 0:00:07 [13.3GiB/s] [====================================================================================>] 100%            

 Performance counter stats for 'sh -c < /dev/zero pv -s 100G -S > /dev/null':

          7,501.68 msec task-clock                #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
                37      context-switches          #    0.005 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               198      page-faults               #    0.026 K/sec                  
    27,916,420,023      cycles                    #    3.721 GHz                      (75.00%)
    62,787,377,126      instructions              #    2.25  insn per cycle           (74.99%)
    15,361,951,954      branches                  # 2047.801 M/sec                    (75.03%)
        51,741,595      branch-misses             #    0.34% of all branches          (74.98%)

       7.505304560 seconds time elapsed

       1.768600000 seconds user
       5.733786000 seconds sys
```

There’s some parallelism (“1.267 CPUs utilized”), but it doesn’t make up for the huge difference in the number of context switches.

Things could be worse, considering the data path — in the first case, data seems to flow from the kernel (`/dev/zero`), to `cat`, back to the kernel (for the pipe), to `pv`, to the kernel (`/dev/null`). In the second, data flows from the kernel, to `pv`, back to the kernel. But in the first scenario, `pv` uses [`splice`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) to copy data from the pipe, avoiding a trip through kernel-owned memory.

Comment: Wow, what a comprehensive answer! Thank you very much, specially for introducing me to this `perf stat` tool